# How can I launch an activity in another apk?

Tags: android

HI,

I have 2 projects (each has its own apk). 
Can you please tell me how can I launch an activity which is in another apk that I created?
I have this activity which I want to launch from another project:

            
                 // what should I put in here so that I can launch this from another activity in another project?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement an Intent interface. I.e. have your activities respond to specific Intents specified via Intent-filters in your manifest. Have a look at this page:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.activity1", "com.activity2");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Activity 1 is the activity that is already running.
Activity 2 is the com name of the activity you want to launch.

Comment: Are you sure about the this ?